# Post-Apocalyptic Desert Movie With Fast Car

Tags: story-identification, movie, post-apocalyptic

I've been trying to remember a movie I watched in my childhood that was likely from the 80s or first few years of the 90s, on late-night cable (maybe on Up All Night on the USA Channel).

I seem to remember it was post-apocalyptic, and the one scene I can recall involved the protagonist getting to choose between a beautiful red Lamborghini type car and a not-so-beautiful gray car. The protagonist chose the gray car because he knew it was a lot more impressive under the hood.

The guy trying to give him the car had been egging him to choose the fancy red one because he knew it wasn't as good. It seemed like it was in a desert environment, and he needed to go fast.

Comment: The Last Chase (1981) with Lee Majors has a red Lambo type car, but it looks like they drive it. See if the movie poster looks familiar. https://i.pinimg.com/236x/9b/b0/46/9bb046ae1e65ac9f6021494394603862--post-apocalyptic-movies-s-neon.jpg

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much for trying. It's not that one, but I'll keep searching. I appreciate the help!

Comment: *Knight Rider 2010* I'm pretty sure had a grey car as well as a huge grey truck, and I think it was set partly in a desert (likely the Mexican border.) Things were either post-apocalyptic, or so run-down and dystopic they might as well have been Post Apoc. But I don't remember the scene with the red car (unless it was an Easter egg throwback to *Knight Rider 2000*)

Comment: Hey! Thanks for trying! The car did look similar to that one, and I believe the gray car and a mounted gun!

Comment: Entirely unsure, because if I have seen these films, it was more than 20 years ago, but could it be one of the "Mad Max" movies? Car chase, Australian wasteland (very desert-like). A gun mounted on one of the cars is in keeping with the theme, too. The first Mad Max was 1979, but a Google search will most likely bring up the more recent in the series (Mad Max: Fury Road from 2015)

Comment: @NurseNerd I am pretty sure the grey car in KR 2010 had two mounted guns on the front. They were positioned very near the front wheels, IIRC.

Comment: @NurseNerd Can you go to https://subslikescript.com/movie/Knight_Rider_2010-110273 and do a ctrl-f for *"this truck isn't fast enough."* Then see if the dialog after that point matches what you remember from the movie.

Comment: One of the _Mad Max_ movies was my first thought based on the title, too, @enkorvaks. Don't recall someone choosing between a shiny Lambo and a grey car, though. (It's been ages since I watched any of 'em - memory might be faulty.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm now pretty sure it was [*Knight Rider 2010*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight_Rider_2010).

> the one scene I can recall involved the protagonist getting to choose between a beautiful red Lamborghini type car and a not-so-beautiful gray car.

There were actually a total of four cars. Three "beautiful" cars, with the second one being red. Then the not-so-beautiful car. It wasn't all-grey at first, but the next scene after it had been "chosen" showed it being extensively modded - after which it was.

> he needed to go fast.

He did. To quote [the script](https://subslikescript.com/movie/Knight_Rider_2010-110273)

> *Yeah, you're going after him,*
> *this truck isn't fast enough.*

The "truck" was the protagonist's monster truck - which now needed to be replaced with a fast car.

[image]

The first car was dismissed as too lightweight - the protagonist would not have been able to mount weapons on it.

> *What can I say?*
> *A legend, creamy, runs like hell.*
>
> *It's nice, but too light.*
>
> *I put a machine gun on*
> *there it's going to flip right over.*

[image]
[image]

Then the red car - a FERRARI! The protagonist didn't want this one either, describing it as "temperamental" - and also quoting some stupid stereotypes about Italians.

[image]

*Side note - this was not the red car from the [previous film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight_Rider_2000). According to Wikipedia, that had been a Dodge Stealth customised to look like a Pontiac Banshee IV.*

Car number three, with the fins, is visible in the background. The protagonist ignored it in favour of seeing what was under that tarp.

[image]

> The guy trying to give him the car had been egging him to choose the fancy red one because he knew it wasn't as good. It seemed like it was in a desert environment, and he needed to go fast.

Not quite. You can see from the photos it was in a desert environment, and the guy had made an effort to hard-sell the other cars. But the reason he didn't want to sell this one was that the engine was busted. However, the protagonist had a souped-up engine hidden away somewhere, and knew that since the car's original engine had been a V8, it wouldn't need *that* much modding to make room for the new one.

And, after a scene in which the car is modded, bulletproofed, and equipped with weaponry... here it is in all its grey ugliness:

[image] [image]

Comment: "a Dodge Stealth customised to look like a Pontiac Banshee IV." man, it's a shame what Hollywood people will do to a car... :(

Comment: @FreeMan I know nothing about Dodges or Pontiacs, so I'll just take your word for it ;-)

Comment: Oh my gosh! That's it!! Thank you! That is so wild you can ask a question on the internet about some random memory and someone from another state can clear it up in a few days. That's the exact random scene that was stuck in my head. Thank you so much dude!! @AJM

Comment: I'm downloading the movie now to rewatch it! So cool!!

Comment: Don't forget to click on the green tick - that marks the question as solved!

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! This was my first post. Thank you again @AJM!